# svg doesn't support ::after

Tags: html, css, svg

this is html and css code. i want to add some style on svg::after. but it doesn't work. although it works well in all html tag. how can i solve it?

```css
    svg {
       font-style: normal;
       color: #fff;
       height: 30px;
       width: 30px;
       background-color: red;
       line-height: 30px;
       display: block;
       text-align: center;
       -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
       -moz-border-radius: 50%;
       border-radius: 50%;
       position: relative;
     }
     svg::after {
       position: absolute;
       left: 50%;
       margin-left: -12px;
       top: 80%;
       content: '';
       height: 0px;
       width: 0px;
       border-top: 1px solid red;
       border-left: 1px solid transparent;
       border-right: 1px solid transparent;
       border-width: 15px 12px 0 12px;
     }
```

```html
 

    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-bars fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="bars" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
    <path fill="currentColor" d="M16 132h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16V76c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16C7.163 60 0 67.163 0 76v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16zm0 160h416c8.837 0 16-7.163 16-16v-40c0-8.837-7.163-16-16-16H16c-8.837 0-16 7.163-16 16v40c0 8.837 7.163 16 16 16z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: As you said in your title, it's not allowed. If your SVG is inline in HTML you coud wrap it in a <div> and apply the ::after to the <div>

Comment: thanks Robert Longson

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap a `div` arround the SVG. This should solve your Problem.